# Can I tag photos in digikam using only the keyboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys, digikam

Ideally I want to hit a key combo and start typing the name of a tag while a dialog box shows a list of matching tags I can select from (a bit like the tag box when you ask a question on this site :). Using a mouse makes it quite a bit slower when working through lots of photos ...

And I am aware that in digikam 2.x I can apply a keyboard shortcut to a single tag, but that doesn't really do what I want. It just applies that tag to the currently selected photos - I can't just type and search in the subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I found this [blog article describing efficient ways to tag photos in digikam](http://www.digikam.org/drupal/node/641).

To make it easier to find, here is their "method B" which allows you to use the keyboard only across your entire range of tags:

> 1. select an album
> 2. switch to "view image"-view (the bigger the picture, the better you can recognize the people, you want to tag)
> 3. switch the right sideview to "Caption/Tags" and select tab "Tags"
> 4. click in the uppermost input box, which shows the text: "Enter new tag here..."
> 5. look for the leftmost person, you have not tagged yet
> 6. start typing a few letters of the desired tagname (You have to start with the first letters in your
>      tag name. There is no "mid word matching".)
>      -> you will see a list of possible tags appear that shrinks with every letter you add to the input box
> 7. if the list is reduced enough, use TAB to select the desired tag from this list
> 8. hit ENTER to assign this tag to your picture
> 9. if there are more persons, you want to tag, go to step 5 again
> 10. if all persons on this image have been tagged, hit PAGE_DOWN to go to the next image and
>       resume with step 5

I could also add that one option you will be given while typing is to add the tag under the currently selected tag. Perfect :)

Comment: You can also hit "T" to jump back into the tag input box, e.g. if you accidentally hit Enter twice (which will jump to the next image, but defocus the input box).